# Using Glass (v5) to query a bucket for a certain template containing value in name

Tags: glass-mapper

I have had a to get child items in a tree where their name contains a value. This was working until I updated the node (and its templates) to be a bucket. Now I can't get the query to return anything.

I have the item with item name "myItem-123" in the bucket. Typing "123" in the bucket search in the client UI returns the item just fine. "clients" is the bucket in the tree.

```
var getItemBuilder = new GetItemByPathBuilder()
            .Path("/sitecore/content/Client Content/Global/Settings/clients//*")
            .AddParam($"123");

        var clientSetting = this.contentRepository.GetItem<IMyInterface>(getItemBuilder.Options);
```

I can use this XPath in XPath builder and it returns the time (I have to use the full name but even with the full name in the addparam call I still get nothing).

I had this all setup and working before I changed it to an item bucket. Not sure how the item bucket change would have broken this. Am I not understand the "AddParam" method correctly?

I have tried a number of GetItems method and GetItemsOptions that match other queries I have done and all those fail as well. It seems whatever I try to query items in a bucket fails.

```
var getItems2 = new GetItemsByQueryOptions(new Query("/sitecore/content/Client Content/Global/Settings/clients/*"));

var test2 = this.contentRepository.GetItems<IClientViewTemplate>(getItems2);
```

This also errors out saying the operation is not supported

My mapping looks like this.

```
this.Map(
            config =>
            {
                config.AutoMap();
                config.TemplateId("MyTemplateGUId");
                config.EnforceTemplateAndBase();
                config.Field(x => x.ViewTemplate).FieldId("MyFieldGUID");
            });
```

Comment: Not really an answer, but you shouldn't be using sitecore queries to get results like this.  If you have a bucket and you need to get a result, best practice dictates that you handle this using the Content Search API instead.  Mostly because you are using a recursive query to get your results which if there ends up being thousands of items in your bucket (which is why you typically use a bucket) your results could take an extended time to return.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I found. I need to play more with the `AddParams` method as I don't fully understand what that is doing. I got the query to work with the below code (if there is a better way please let me know) and wanted to post in case it could help anyone else.

```
var getItems = new GetItemByQueryBuilder()
                .Query($"<rootPath>//*[contains(@@name,'{myParam.ToLower()}')]");
var mySetting = this.contentRepository.GetItem<IMyTemplate>(getItems.Options);
```